# Creating table Entity Framework Core and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

Using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite`, I'm attempting to create a code level creation of a database, and add a simple row to a table. I get the error, `SQLite error: no such table Jumplists`.

From last to first, here are the classes

```
using JumpList_To_Clipboard.Data.Tables;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace JumpList_To_Clipboard.Data
{
    public class DataSQLite : IData
    {
        public const string DATABASE = "data.sqlite";

        public DataSQLite()
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteDbContext(DATABASE))
            {
                // Ensure database is created with all changes to tables applied
                db.Database.Migrate();

                db.JumpLists.Add(new JumpList { Name = "Default" });
                db.SaveChanges(); // Exception thrown here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DbContext class

```
using JumpList_To_Clipboard.Data.Tables;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace JumpList_To_Clipboard.Data
{
    class SQLiteDbContext : DbContext
    {
        readonly string db_path;

        public DbSet<JumpList> JumpLists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public SQLiteDbContext(string database) : base()
        {
            db_path = database;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(string.Format("Data Source={0}", db_path));
        }
    }
}
```

The JumpList class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JumpList_To_Clipboard.Data.Tables
{
    public class JumpList
    {
        public int JumpListId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The other two classes aren't worth repeating here, and don't give errors.

When I use the firefox sqlite extension to look at the `data.sqlite` file, none of my three tables are listed.

The command `db.DataBase.Migrate` says it

> Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database.

What are `pending migrations`? I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on these.

I'm combining examples from:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/

**Edit:** If I replace `db.Database.Migrate();` with `db.Database.EnsureCreated();` it works. From the documentation, `Migrate()` is the same, but lets you create updates to the table structures, where `EnsureCreated()` does not. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

Microsoft has a serious issue making decent documentation, but I did find a site that has somewhat dated documentation for [Learning Entity Framework Core](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations), specifically migrations which is in the link.

At the top, it mentions,

> If you have Visual Studio, you can use the Package Manager Console (PMC) to manage migrations.

Which led to the [Package Manager Console](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/commands/pmc-commands) page which states right at the top, that you need to have:

> If you want to use the Package Manager Console to execute migrations command, you need to ensure that the latest version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is added to your `project.json` file.

The problem is, there is no `project.json` file anywhere in my project (or solution). After some searching, I found that via NuGet, to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

Then via `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console` I was able to run the `add-migration InitialDatabases` command. The last part `InitialDatabases` is the name of the class it creates for you, and sticks in a folder called Migrations at the base of the project.

Now when:

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

is run, all is well!

Comment: Here's some extremely hard to find documentation by Microsoft on EF Core Migrations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

Comment: @bricelam I looked at the "Getting Started" page of that, and since it wasn't what I was looking for at the time. Binding WCF and EFC, I moved on. Good to know. I think you were being sarcastic, but check out the official docs [Getting Started](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/) and [EF Core with WPF and .Net](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/) and you'll see what I mean. They don't even contain the off quoted Blog example. If you fix it, add binding posts, selecting blog in a combo-box, and populating posts all within code and xaml.

Comment: No sarcasm. There is a serious lack of documentation, and what documentation there is is impossible to find and navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (worked for me in a project a few months ago, i don't remember why):

```
 public virtual DbSet<JumpList> JumpLists { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Also i had to use LONG instead of INT for classes ID because sqlite uses LONG as default for table ID, so after when you do a CRUD operation it fails because it can't compare/convert/cast LONG(64) to INT(32).